# Display rows in table on change of drop down

Tags: javascript, dropdown

I have drop down with months. January, February,....,November, December. When January is selected in table are displayed 31 rows for all 31 days.But when February is selected then there are also 28 February, 29 January, 30 January, 31 January. 
I have this code on change

```js
$("#selectMonth").change(function () {

            selectedMonth = $("#selectMonth").val();

            table = document.getElementById("mpProfileTableDaily_MWh");
            rows = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");

            for(i = 0; i < rows.length; i++){
                rows[i].style.background = "transparent";
            }
         if(selectedMonth == 'january'){
                rowNum = 1;
                @foreach($january->month_dates as $day)
                row = document.getElementById("mpProfileTableDaily_MWh").rows[rowNum].cells;
  row[0].innerHTML = "{{$day}}";
                    m = 1;
@endforeach
......
```

The some code is also for other months. 
How to solve this?

[image]

Comment: Can you update the code snippet.. its having error

Answer (score 1):

Add

```
rows[i].innerHTML= "";
```

after

```
rows[i].style.background = "transparent";
```

in for loop

Comment: error> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of undefined